# How do logstash configs work

Tags: centos, logstash, elastic-stack

Running logstash 2.4 on Centos 7

So there seems to be zero documentation for this on Elastic's web site, but I have found in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) as well as some other links that you can break up your configs in /etc/logstash/conf.d and logstash, when run as a service, will aggregate them.

The thing is in the article I linked to they are creating separate configs for inputs, outputs, and filters.

Ideally I'd prefer to have a single config for each log type that includes the inputs, outputs, and filters for that log type. Is this possible and is there any official documentation explaining how to run logstash as a daemon this way- if so where is Elastic hiding it?

Answer (score 1):

Basically `logstash` conf is the file which contains the input, filter and output sectors. `Input` is where you give the path for your input data file such as log files or a database or any other doc types. `Filtering` is where you can mutate db fields or do some grok filtering if the input is a log file. `Output` is where you mention, what's the index to store all the docs and assign other output parameters such as `host`, `document_id` etc according to your need.

You could either create the index initially using ES and push all the documents to it, or you could create it through `logstash` conf itself, where it creates the index when you run the conf file.

You could have more than one logstash conf files if you need. If you're handling more than one type of documents, it'll be easy if you have different conf files for those. [These](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/command-line-flags.html) are the available flags you could use, when you run the `logstash` config.

[logstash samples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html)